# Are monotone functions (when talking about Reals) assumed to be from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ (i.e. one dimensional)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

assuming there isn't some other information specified.

That is, I am if, say, I see a function defined as 
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}\equiv (h\circ g)(x)
$$
with $h$ monotone, can I assume that $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Edit: I should note: I'm not asking if this is *always* the case: rather, I am wondering if whether, if a statement is not very precise, in general it would be safe to assume that $h$ is intended to be $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Monotone" only makes sense for a function defined on an ordered set.  While there are certainly other ordered sets than $\mathbb R$, and it would have been better to have a more precise statement, in this context I would think it safe to assume that the intent was for $h$ to be defined on a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Note: you can define "monotone" for a poset too, which is frequent in some fields (then you just want $h(x) \leq h(y)$ whenever $x\preceq y$, for non-decreasing); so that you don't necessarily need total order. But if that were the case, the authors would (or should) have specified it.

Answer (score 0):

For a function h to be monotonic, you need that as the domain is increasing, the value of h is either only increasing or only decreasing. In $\mathbb R^n$, there is not a well defined sense of order (as you can increase or decrease in any of the n directions) and so you can't really say that the vectors are increasing. So in your example, it would be safe to assume $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.